# Nice way to multiply each row of a matrix by a vector in r

Tags: r

I know this is a really basic question, sorry.

I want to multiply each row of a matrix by a vector. So I have:

```
mat=matrix(1,2,4)
vec=c(1,2,3,4)

#works but ugly:
new.mat=mat
for(i in 1:nrow(mat)){
  new.mat[i,]=mat[i,]*vec
}
```

I thought I'd found the answer with 'apply' but I couldn't get it to work the same way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
t( t(mat) * vec )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

`*` like most other operators in R is vectorised. The `t` is necessary because R will recycle column-wise. The `apply` solution is:

```
t( apply( mat , 1 , `*` , vec ) )
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

Answer (score 4):

using `apply`

```
> t(apply(mat,1 , function(x) x*vec))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
```

Comment: Very elegant way, like Simon. I upvoted yours because I like the function to be contained in a single part instead of being splited by a comma

Answer (score 2):

I'd have to say the most elegant way to go about this is:

```
mat=matrix(1,2,4)
vec=1:4
new.mat=t(vec*t(mat))
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer `sweep`, although I think it's marginally slower:

```
sweep(mat,MARGIN=2,vec,"*")
```

`MARGIN=2` specifies that each *column* (margin 2) should be multiplied by the corresponding element of `vec`.